# Convergence Problem of an exponential

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, precision-and-accuracy

I want to evaluate the following integral numerically

```
NIntegrate[w E^(-w/0.001)/(w(w-0.0001))^2), {w,0, 0.0001, 1},
MaxRecursion -> 300, AccuracyGoal -> 10, Method -> "PrincipalValue"]
```

It gives the error

> Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small

It seems that a lot of questions arose regarding this problem in the community, but I didn't find any concrete solution. I really appropriate if anyone help me out with a solution?

Comment: It seems that `w=0` is another location of singularity?

Comment: @tablecircle Yeah. But I think that the principal value method takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Your Integral doesn't converge at all, it is Infinity, therefore the error message. As you see, the Denominator ist 0 at w=0 and at w=.0001. Make a logarithmic Plot to see it.
Next hint: often it is better to use rationalized values instead of real numbers.
Principalvalue only makes sense, if a positive part at the singularity is compensated by an equal large negative part. You have only positive parts at 0 and .0001.

```
       In[60]:= LogPlot[w E^(-w/0.001)/(w (w - 0.0001))^2, {w, 0, .0002}, 
MaxRecursion -> 15]

   In[9]:= w E^(-w 1000)/(w (w - 1/10000))^2

 Out[9]= E^(-1000 w)/((-(1/10000) + w)^2 w)

  In[38]:= Plot[((-(1/10000) + w)^2 w), {w, 0, 2/10000}]

  In[27]:= sol = Solve[(-(1/10000) + w)^2 w == 0, w]

   Out[27]= {{w -> 0}, {w -> 1/10000}, {w -> 1/10000}}

   In[29]:= E^(-1000 w) /. sol // N

   Out[29]= {1., 0.904837, 0.904837}

   In[35]:= 1/((-(1/10000) + w)^2 w) // ExpandAll

  Out[35]= 1/(w/100000000 - w^2/5000 + w^3)

   In[57]:= Integrate[w E^(-w 1000)/(w (w - 1/10000))^2, {w, 0,   1/100000}]

    During evaluation of In[57]:= Integrate::idiv: Integral of      E^(-1000 w)/((-(1/10000)+w)^2 w) does not converge on {0,1/100000}. >>

    Out[57]= \!\(
   \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), 
   FractionBox[\(1\), \(100000\)]]\(
  \*FractionBox[
  SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-1000\)\ w\)], \(
  \*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-
  \*FractionBox[\(1\), \(10000\)]\) + 
       w)\), \(2\)]\ w\)] \[DifferentialD]w\)\)

     In[58]:= Integrate[w E^(-w 1000)/(w (w - 1/10000))^2, {w,   1/100000, 1}]

     During evaluation of In[58]:= Integrate::idiv: Integral of      E^(-1000 w)/((-(1/10000)+w)^2 w) does not converge on {1/100000,1}. >>

    Out[58]= \!\(
  \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), 
  FractionBox[\(1\), \(100000\)], \(1\)]\(
  \*FractionBox[
 SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-1000\)\ w\)], \(
  \*SuperscriptBox[\((\(-
 \*FractionBox[\(1\), \(10000\)]\) + 
   w)\), \(2\)]\ w\)] \[DifferentialD]w\)\)

     In[64]:= Plot[
     w E^(-w 1000)/(w (w - 1/10000))^2, {w, -1/100000, 1/100000}]

     In[65]:= NIntegrate[
    w E^(-w 1000)/(w (w - 1/10000))^2, {w, -1/100000, 0, 1/100000}, 
    Method -> "PrincipalValue"]

     Out[65]= 3.82496*10^7
```